# is there a way to get Cluster JVM's details in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Consider a application running on a cluster which has 4 Servers ( Server1,Server2,Server3,Server 4 )

is there a way to find out all 4 server details using java ?

Actually i am trying to cache/invalidate the value across the cluster (distributed servers).

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent upon what system you're using to manage the clusters, and has very little to do with the language in which you're running the code in.

If you're trying to cache/invalidate a value across a distributed system, you should probably be using an external tool to manage that state like memcache across the servers.